# Yeoman Generator cannot read property Base of undefined with 1.1 version

Tags: node.js, yeoman, yeoman-generator, yeoman-generator-angular

I started using the Yeoman Generators in which i'm building my own with the generator-generator and per a few tutorials I have a main  index.js file in which this code is used

index.js

```
var yeoman = require('yeoman-generator');
var chalk = require('chalk');
var yosay = require('yosay');

module.exports = yeoman.generators.Base.extend({
.....
```

Yeoman generator that "works" is  `0.19.0`

packages.json

```
"dependencies": {
"yeoman-generator": "^0.19.0",
```

However, If I change to the latest version of `Yeoman` of  `1.1.1`  then it fails

```
cannot read property Base of undefined    
yeoman.generators.Base.extend
```

The stuff is all based on Node.js so i'm including it into the tags

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you might guess, 1.0 release came with some breaking change. You should refer to the official documentation: http://yeoman.io/authoring/

```
// 0.x
var Base = require('yeoman-generator').generators.Base;

// 1.x
var Base = require('yeoman-generator');
```

Also see release notes: http://yeoman.io/blog/hello-generator-1.0.html

Comment: Why would this relatively very popular generator called `webapp` not upgrade and still use `0.24.1`  ?     https://github.com/yeoman/generator-webapp#readme

Comment: So for 0.x I do  `module.exports = yeoman.generators.Base.extend({...`

Comment: For 1.x  would I this ?  `module.exports = yeoman.extend({..`

Comment: Oh,  I am first setting require to `yeoman`  , so above i have `var yeoman = require('yeoman-generator');`

Comment: Link to release notes clarifies a lot!